# Starting embedded MSYS bash in the project directory in clion

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin, clion, msys

How can I start the embedded terminal in Clion in the project directory if I am using a custom terminal (like MSYS or Cygwin bash.exe)?

Bash always seems to start in the home directory no matter what the startup directory is set to. Is there a way to force bash to start up in the directory that it is ran in? I tried adding

```
cd "`pwd`"
```

to the .bashrc, but that didn't work.

Here's a screenshot of the terminal settings page in Clion:[image: clion terminal info]

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that by using a windows batch file with the content

```
@echo off
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 && C:\dev\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe --login
```

Then I put the batch file in CLion.
I derived that from the msys2 start script `msys2_shell.cmd` where the environment variable `CHERE_INVOKING` is used to specify that the calling directory is kept.